# Creating DbContext outside of Asp.Net core project

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm fairly new to Dependency Injection, ASP.NET Core and EF Core, so someone please point me to the right direction.

Currently, I have the following codes under the `startup.cs`:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

This works fine if everything is within one project (let's say, `SomeProject.WebApp`). However, I would like to have `MyDbContext` as well as any data operation in a separated project, let's call it `SomeProject.Data`. So far, I have no trouble creating my DbContext class:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
}
```

However, within `SomeProject.Data`, whenever I would like to do any data operation:

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext(How do I fill in here?))
```

I think it is looking for some kind of connection string, however the connection string is located inside the `appsettings.json` which is in the `SomeProject.Webapp`.

Comment: `DbContext` has a parameterless constructor you can also use.

Comment: `public MyDbContext() : base(options)` is not valid, it is still looking for the `DbContextOptions` at the options part

Comment: Try `public MyDbContext() : base()` instead.